# XML Error: Not well formed

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I got this error that says not well formed and it has to do with xml itself. How do i tell python to ignore a section of the xml file?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <solution version="0.1" run date = "2013-04-01">
        <description />
        <drillholes total_holes="302" total_drilhole_cost="6190">
```

That is the beginning of the file and the error occurs at run date = blah blah, how do i get python to ignore that section without getting rid of the code, Thanks

Comment: Where do you get that file from?

Comment: dear @user2386695, please accept one of the answers, if you think they were helpful to you. Thanks! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code is not a well-formed XML file. This should be it:

— ***first:*** you always need a root object (in your case, this is `<solution>`, **second:** you always have to close every opened tag, **third:** you can't ever use spaces in attribute names (in your case: `run date`).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<solution version="0.1" run_date="2013-04-01">
    <description />
    <drillholes total_holes="302" total_drilhole_cost="6190" />
</solution>
```

**EDITED:**

Your only problem is in the attribute name. You have to fix that, and everything is going to be fine then.

Comment: this was mentioned to be a partial file, though

Comment: yepp, you are right, so the only problem he has, is the space in the attribute name.. I fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Not-well formed remains non-well formed. Every XML parser will complain about your file.
If you don't have valid XML then don't use an XML parser. The case is very clear. If you want to parse your crap format then use stuff like BeautifulSoup or write your own crap-data-aware parser. End of discussion.